# Runnig Ex-crawler

Tags: log4j, web-crawler

Hi i am runnig  the jar of this open source [Ex-Crawler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ex-crawler/files/Ex-Crawler%20Distributed%20Client%20%28gui%29/)

But i always receive this error :
og4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (eu.medsea.mimeutil.TextMimeDetector).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info

Answer (score 0):

The application you're running uses log4j to produce log files. And log4j needs a configuration file, usually named **log4j.properties**, to be available in the application's class path, in order to start properly.

This is sample of default configuration you might start with:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```